# Get the index of the selected row of a ListView in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, listview

I want to get the index of the row that I select in my ListView.

```
item = New ListViewItem(Name)
Dim indexItem As Integer
indexItem = item.Tag
```

When I compile, It occurs an error; Between the advice of VS there are:
-Exstablish if the object is null before you call the method
-Use the word New to create an instance of object

Can you help me?

Comment: What has the code shown to do with identifying the selected item? How do you expect a newly created item with only the `Name` being set having a value for the `Tag` property?

Comment: If I select a row, i want to get the index of the item. A programmer said to me to use item.Tag and it doens't work

Comment: You have been lead astray (or said programmer just wanted to get rid of you): See [ListView.SelectedIndices Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindices(v=vs.110).aspx) and [ListView.SelectedIndexChanged Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You need to get a handle on what `New` does.  Your code creates a new listview item which will never ever be related to the one Selected by the user.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].